# C# loop oneshot function

Tags: c#, function, loops, skip

I have an interesting situation here.  Language is C#, using Visual Studio.

I have a function-loop that is going to keep running through.

When a certain event triggers, I want a function to be called using an IF statement.

Is there a way I can have this function not be called again under a certain time delay?

For instance, Function A is called....Function A cannot be called no matter what in the next 20 seconds again.

After 20 seconds, Function A can be called again if the IF statement exists.

I have a function that is texting my phone, currently my loop is super fast so it texts my phone like 20 times in a few seconds. I want to limit this.
I also cannot have the event trigger a while loop to make it go through another loop.

I need the loop to keep running its cycle but skip the function that texts my phone until a certain time has passed.

Comment: Show us your attempt to do this in code? Its a perfect beginner task.

Comment: I guess the problem is a little deeper than I initially described.  The event to trigger Function A is near the beginning of the loop.  So if I simply used an INT assignment by the time it gets to the beginning of the loop, this int gets reset.  My code has sensitive information so it is hard to simply copy and paste it.  I was mainly looking for a built in library that can handle this via a .Tick command or something

Comment: Its a single loop with an if statement, there is nothing sensitive or complex about that. Just use a `TimeSpan` and `if (ts.ElapsedMilliSeconds > delay) Function();`

Comment: Define a static variable to hold the date and time of the last sent message. Modify your “send message” function to check this variable before sending anything. After sending a message update the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Timer:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
 myTimer.Interval = 200; //double timer interval in ms
 myTimer.Elapsed += myTimer_Elapsed;
 myTimer.Start();
```

Then put your function inside myTimer_Elapsed:

```
void myTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        your_function();
    }
```

Stop it using myTimer.Stop();

Comment: Kindly mark as an answer if your problem was solved by this answer. Thanks.